# Android Getting a static wrong Location

Tags: android, gps, location

I have a text view to show my Latitude and Longitude, now the problem is that i always get the couple (32,35) (which is somewhere in some ocean i think), I even went out for a walk to give the gps a chance yet i got nothing.

I wanted to see if its something to do with my phone or the gps in my phone so i went on and opened Waze app and saw it actually does work.

what can be the problem?

here is a snippet of my simple code:

```
public class Main extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    private LocationManager manager;
    private TextView tv;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText("Hello There");
        manager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        tv.setText((int)location.getLatitude()+ ","+ (int)location.getLongitude());
    }
...
}
```

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem: he says he is getting valus (32,35)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
tv.setText(location.getLatitude()+ ","+location.getLongitude());
```

instead of

```
tv.setText((int)location.getLatitude()+ ","+ (int)location.getLongitude());
            ^^^                               ^^^
```

because you are converting `latitude` and `longitude` to `int` and in your case you may be getting minor changes.

like

```
32.110 35.500  you will get (32,35)
32.120 35.540  you will get (32,35)
32.180 35.580  you will get (32,35)
32.200 35.900  you will get (32,35)
32.290 35.880  you will get (32,35)
   ^^^    ^^^
```